# Need Help With jQuery Hidden Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery code where when I click on a peice of text another div appears above it, but the div just go's on top of the original div, but what i want is for the new div to push the orignal div down with it.

This is the code

HTML:

```
  <div id="social">Content to Show</div>  
  <div id="joinus">  <center><a id="activator" href="#">Join Us</a></center></div>
  <div id="outerbody">
```

CSS:

```
#joinus {
    background-image:url(../IMG/JoinUsBottom.png);
    width:327px;
    height:83px;
    position:absolute;
    left:755px;
    font-size:30px;
}
#social {
    background-image:url(../IMG/JoinUsTop.png);
    width:327px;
    heght:99px;
    position:absolute;
    left:755px;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#activator").click(function(){
                $("#social").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        }); 
 </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Keiron:could you please rephrase the question (Title) so that it's easier to understand what you want? "Need help with jQuery" says nothing about the issue you are describing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both in a parent div, which is positioned absolute.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="social">Content to Show</div>  
<div id="joinus">  <center><a id="activator" href="#">Join Us</a></center></div>
</div>

#joinus {
    background-image:url(../IMG/JoinUsBottom.png);
    height:83px;
    font-size:30px;
}
#social {
    background-image:url(../IMG/JoinUsTop.png);;
    height:99px;
    display:none;
}
#wrapper {
    width:327px
    left:755px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got no opening div of #outerbody in you example.
Anyway, what I suggest, is:

```
<div id=outer style='position:absolute'>
  <div id=moreinfo style='position:nothing!, display:none'> bla bla bla
  <div onclick=showmoreinfo>button</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example page: http://www.capsule.hu/help/slide_content.html - just wrap the two divs into a wrapper div and use position: absolute property for that with the same horizontal dimensions... but check the source and it will be clear